# Redirect link in index.html

Tags: php, html, file, url

Not sure where i am going wrong here...

I have a form that has a php file that is actioned when submit is pressed. 
Basically there are two fields, one is the url and the other the file name that the php file will create.

I need to amend a html file, with the url several times a week, but would also like to create new file for backup.

I have the following two files..

```
    <form action="action_page.php">
    YT Link:<br>
    <input type="text" name="ytlink" value="www.google.com">
    <br>
    File Name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="FName" value="test">
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
```

and the php file..

```
    <?php
    $myfile = fopen("$FName", "w");
    $txt = "text update here\n";
    fwrite($myfile, $txt);
    fclose($myfile);
    ?>
```

But when i run the form it does nothing.. any help would be much appreciated. As you can see i am very new to php.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The first thing you should learn when studying php is `$_GET` and `$_POST` which answers half of your question. The other half is that files need paths.

Comment: If you are tring to get your php to accept info from your html file, you need to add something like `method="POST"` or `method="GET"` to your form tag

Comment: Please be nice to others, just because you have 6k doesn't mean you can talk down to people.

Answer (score 1):

you forgot to take the value in post

```
<?php
$Fname= $_POST['Fname']; //add this line
$myfile = fopen("$FName", "w");
$txt = "text update here\n";
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
fclose($myfile);
?>
```

Comment: Tried that, but still doesnt create the file that i specified.. must be something that i am missing again.

Comment: are you puting the extension while sending the filename value. eg: file1.txt or file3.txt

Comment: Yes, I put a link in the url and the file name as index.html

Comment: @yardyy  You need to add `method="POST"` or `"method="GET"` to your `<form>` tag in the html document so that it knows to send your data to the php form.

Comment: I just added the method="POST" command into the form now, and its the same.

Also i checked the permissions on the folder and files and they all set to 777

Comment: @jared I just added the method="POST" command into the form now, and its the same. Also i checked the permissions on the folder and files and they all set to 777

Comment: @yardyy I'm sure you have already done this, just trying to cover the bases. Is the name in your `action` tag correct?  Is the path in your `action` tag correct? Field names being posted are spelled correctly?

Comment: Hi, 

I just managed to cobble together some code and got most of it working.. 

Form.html
        <form action="cr.php" method="POST">
        YT Link   :<input type="text" name="ytlink" value="" size="75" >             
        File Name:<input type="text" name="fname" value="" size="9" >
        Extension:<input type="text" name="extension" value=".php" >
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

Comment: then the cr.php file

        <?php
        $ytlink=$_POST['ytlink'];
        $fname=$_POST['fname'];
        $extension=$_POST['extension'];
        $myFile = $fname.$extension;
        $fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
        $stringData = "header('Location: $ytlink');\n";
        fwrite($fh, $stringData);
        fclose($fh);
        ?>

Comment: now that seems to work as i originally wanted.. but

now i want to take a template.html file and insert just the variable ytlink into the specific location in template.html, and then save that with the $fname.$extension variable.. 

am thinking i have to do something with apend, but dont know the syntax..

hope that makes sense

Comment: sorry not sure why its showing as three different comments from me

Comment: Might be easier if you edit your question.  It's a little difficult to read as comments.